# Find the number of boolean functions of n variable that satisfy the following condition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebras

For how many boolean functions is this true? The length of the shortest disjunctive normal form of that functions is equal to 2^(n-1). And the the number of variable entries in the minimal dnf of that functions is equal to             n*(2^(n-1)-1).

Comment: By the length of the shortest dnf I mean the number of elementary conjunctions in it. And by the number of variables in the minimal dnf I mean the number of variable entries in it.

Comment: Sorry I am still not sure I understand. Do you mean by the number of variable entries the sum of lengths of the elementary conjunctions?

Comment: Yes,that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: So the average length of a minterm is slightly less than n?  Are there any restrictions on the number of distinct variables? (If one is allowed only n/2 variables, this strongly limits the choices.) How is this problem motivated?  Gerhard "Have You Tried Gate Arrays?" Paseman, 2016.02.28.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Actually I shamelessly played around with the data, and the answer seems to be $2^n$; all such dnfs seem to have $n$ minterms of length $n-1$ and $2^{n-1}-n$ minterms of length $n$.

Comment: (in fact it is not difficult to list these $2^n$ explicitly; I just do not see how to show that there are no others)

Comment: You have to be careful which "short" minterms you pick.  For n=3, ab and ab' cannot both belong to a minimal dnf.  Also, some minterms might be shorter.  Gerhard "Bad With Really Big K-Maps" Paseman, 2016.02.28.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I've double-checked, is OK. E. g. for $n=3$ one has eight dnfs obtained from $ab\lor ac\lor bc\lor a'b'c'$ substituting $a\leftarrow a'$, $b\leftarrow b'$, $c\leftarrow c'$ in all (eight) possible ways.